# Draw semi circle with bottom line to use it as skshapenode in spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to draw a semi circle with the bottom line and reuse it as shape node again. How can I implement this. This is my code for semi circle.
And also some code is hard coded so some help is appreciated.

```
func drawLine(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) {
// for line
    let myLine = SKShapeNode()
    let myPath = CGMutablePath()
    myPath.addLines(between: [from, to])
    myLine.path = myPath
    myLine.strokeColor = SKColor.blue
    myLine.lineWidth = 4
    addChild(myLine)
}
func drawSemi(){
// for semi circle

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 50, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
    
    let pathNode = SKShapeNode(path: bezierPath.cgPath)
    
    pathNode.strokeColor = SKColor.blue
    
    pathNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    
    
    pathNode.lineWidth = 3
    
    
    
    addChild(pathNode)
}
func drawCompleteSemi(){
    drawSemi()
    drawLine(from: CGPoint(x: 450, y: 500), to: CGPoint(x: 550, y: 500))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply call `close()` on your bezier path, and omit the drawline function entirely

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 50, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
bezierPath.close() //<-- add this line
```